# Android remove views from a grid

Tags: android

I was testing the code found at the following Android developer site
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Can anyone tell how i can remove item onclick. 
I have tried removeInLayout which works but the remove image keeps showing up again afterwards. other function removeAt(position) etc are crashing

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how much you've modified hello gridview example, so I will describe the procedure for unmodified example.

First, you have to modify you "data storage" so you can easily remove an item from it, for example create a list from `mThumbIds` array in the `ImageAdapter` constructor, store it as a field and remember to modify `getView()` and `getCount()` methods to use it.

Next, simply remove an item from the list in `onItemClick()` method of the listener and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on the `ImageAdapter` instance, that you need to store as a final variable

```
    final ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            adapter.mThumbIdsList.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

The trick is that grid view displays items basing on the content of bound data (a list or an array in this example case) , so to remove an item form the grid you have to remove and item from your bound data.